# Error showing on every project in Eclipse and I haven't changed anything

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just opened Eclipse as I need to make some changes in an existing project. I added a new file to my 'Raw' folder and refreshed the folder and when I went to build it shows a error 'x' on the project but not against any of the source files, etc. It also shows an error against every other project in Eclipse even though I haven't touched any of them

If anyone has come accross this problem before please let me know how I can rectify it.

Comment: maybe is something with the name of file, like there are some capital letters?

Comment: In Eclipse, go to window-> show view-> Error and let us know error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the problem. You need to delete the debug.keynote file in .android which had expired! Then clean and rebuild your app and the debug.keynote file will be recreated and the error removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have several times problems with Eclipse highlighting everything with errors even when everything is fine. 
Sometimes it looks like Eclipse caches the errors and does not clear them properly.

In those cases, I tried different things such as:

- removed the file you just added. Refresh and clean the project and see if it has fixed it.
- Remove project from Eclipse and import it again.
- Close Eclipse and open it again.

For me, the above sometimes work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might with unresolved build resources. like some previously used path might not be available now. You can goto the properties of the project and check in the respective tabs if some of the paths earlier set are not valid anymore.

Comment: I've rebooted and tried all of the above and my paths are unchanged. I also created a new project and when I compiled after changing nothing I get the same error!

Comment: As @jitendra sharma mentioned can you post what exactly is the error from the error view?

Comment: The first error was 'Unable to read C:\Steve_Stuff\Android\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml:' then I created a new project and compiled without doing anything and I got 'An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing external folders".' followed by 'Failed to load properties file for project 'Test1''